# Configure Twitter Gem on Ruby

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

I'm trying to get the Twitter Gem working in a simple Ruby script, but am having trouble just setting the configuration.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end

Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
```

Every time I try to run this code from terminal using 'ruby twitter.rb' I get back the following error

**tweet2.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end**

Line 8 would be

```
config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
```

I don't understand why keyword_end would be expected here. Can anyone help me out?

By the way I'm using ruby 1.9.2p320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mistake was caused by not making the values strings by putting them in double quotes. Fixed code looks like

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.oauth_token = "YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN"
  config.oauth_token_secret = "YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET"
end

Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
```